# What could cause PIC GPIO pins to fail short to ground?

Tags: pic, failure

I have a [PIC18F2420](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39631E.pdf) in a design that has now had two instances of the Port C0 pin failing short to ground. The first instance, we literally finished some testing, and went home for the night. When we came back the next morning, the pin was dead. In that case, it worked for over a week. In the second instance, the pin sat idle for most of a day before failing. When I desolder the PIC, it measures about 1 Ohm, from C0 to the Vss pin.

The only peripheral that uses this pin is Timer 1. It is the oscillator output, and is disabled.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZd2O2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The switching is happening very slowly, < 1 Hz. We measured 275 mV of overshoot on the high to low transition, but nothing significant going low to high. The overshoot is close to the absolute minimum, but is it enough to kill the pin? There is another pin with an identical configuration that is toggled much more often, and it has remained rock solid.

Comment: High to low transition...do you mean undershoot? -275mV? What is your PIC supply Vdd, I'm guessing 5V due to the pullup but just wondering.

Comment: If you are not configuring the pin C0 as an open drain then when you set it high and SW1 is closed it will be shorted to ground. the current will be vary high as the diode will only drop 0.7V. Most pins will have some limiting to deal with short transients but if it is held for a long time then you will damage the pin.

Comment: @dext0rb Yes, 5V supply, and call it undershoot.

Comment: @DeathBySnuSnu The pin is configured as an input. It worked exactly as designed for over a week. We're all genuinely confused as to why it randomly shorted. We use this configuration all over the place on lots of products.

Comment: Log the datecodes of tfailing devices and production lots. Maybe reveals nothing, but ...

Comment: @MattYoung Measure the resistance from your 5V source to PORTC0 if your still getting 1 Ohm and not approximately 3.9K you've got a short circuit somewhere. Also if possible isolate the left side of your circuit by removing the diode and see how that goes.

Comment: Can we have a picture of the pin area, and test environment?  I would suspect esd, although denied below.  This won't be an accident, somewhere the maximum ratings are being exceeded.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what the external input actually is too.

Comment: @ErikFriesen I suspect injection current since a series resistor resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still unable to say exactly what caused this issue, but I think it had something to do with a logic low injection current violation. I changed my input circuitry to include a current limiting resistor in series with the pin. The boards went through a couple more weeks of testing, and were shipped, and the issue has not popped back up since.

Answer (score 0):

Most PIC port pins have diodes to VCC and ground to protect the input, similar to what is shown below (though likely not 1n4148s!)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIsPE9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

ESD and/or overvoltage can literally melt these diodes, causing a short to ground (or sometimes to VCC).  This is possible in your circuit as you have no current limiting resistor in series with the input.  I've seen this happen on a variety of different PICs.  My suspicion for you is ESD -- electro static discharge.

Comment: I highly doubt the answer is ESD. Both units have exhibited identical failures, and have spent their lives on an ESD mat.

Comment: I might look for over- or under-voltaging on the pin with sufficient current to fry the protection diode, then.